# How to know which constructor I am using

Tags: java, constructor, invoke

I hava a class which contents two construcors and a method. the return value of the method depends which construor I m calling. I made a simple program here (It doesn't work).

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class TestUsingConstructor {

    public TestUsingConstructor(String string) {
        System.out.println("String as param !");
    }

    public TestUsingConstructor(int i) {
        System.out.println("Int as param !");
    }


    public void CalledMethod (){
        if(this.usingConstructor() == 1){
            System.out.println("Get 'int' Constructor");
        }else if(this.usingConstructor() == 2){
            System.out.println("Get 'String' Constructor");
        }
    }

    public int usingConstructor() {
        Constructor[] allConstructors = this.getClass().getConstructors();
        for (Constructor constructor : allConstructors) {
            Class<?>[] pType = constructor.getParameterTypes();
            for (int i = 0; i < pType.length; i++) {
                if (pType[i].equals(int.class)) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 2;
                }
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestUsingConstructor t1 = new TestUsingConstructor(1);

        t1.CalledMethod();

        //TestUsingConstructor t2 = new TestUsingConstructor("test");

        //t2.CalledMethod();
    }
}
```

what I want to get the result like:

Int as param !
"Get 'int' Constructor"

but this exemple's result is:

Int as param !
Get 'String' Constructor

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not set a flag in the constructors and check it in `CalledMethod()`?

Comment: Without knowing where you are going with this, I do have to say that the whole design sounds a bit iffy.

Comment: You mean I declare a flag inside of each constructor? It sounds a good way to slove this problem. by the way, if I can deal with this by a 'java reflect' way? Thanks, NPE

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I hava a class which has a "size() method" for example, and each constructor has its different parameter like "Person(String [])", "Person(int [])" ... and when I new the object of this class and I want call the "size()", I think I hava to know which constructor I am using. (It's not just for getSize())

Answer (score 0):

I think you make it too complicated just to find out which constructor you are using.

As you message says you are using the `int` constructor.

Your `usingConstructor()` is way too complicated for me to decipher it and obviously does not work properly.

When you write your code for each constructor you know the parameter type:

```
public TestUsingConstructor(int i) {
    // inside here you KNOW that your parameter is int. Isn't that enough?
}
```

Another solution for me (if I want to check overriden methods etc) is to debug the program and see which method invokes.

Comment: Thanks Eypros, I just used a 'flag' inside of each constructor. Actually, When I new a "TestUsingConstructor()" as "tus" for example, then, "tus" call "calledMethod()". Then, inside of "calledMathed()", I will do something that depends the parameter of its constructor. But, I think you are right, I just made it more complicated.